# PHP: Identifying the visibility of a class variable

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I have the class:

```
class MyClass {

    protected $protected;
    private $_private;

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

}
```

I want to "magically" get protected variables but not private variables. Is there a built-in PHP function that will help me identify the visibility of a class variable?

Comment: I'm just curious, coming from a C++ background where there's no reflection, *why* would you need such an accessor function, and what sort of design problem does this code solve? (It almost looks like you're trying to treat a class as a sort of database...)

Comment: I need to prevent the magic getter from accessing private variables.

Comment: This looks to me like you just want "protected members to be public", though... why declare them protected in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
foreach ($refClass->getProperties() as $property) {
  if ($property->isProtected()) echo $property->getName();
}
```